# How do I implement an fp growth algorithm?

Tags: mahout

i want to run fp-growth algorithm of Mahout. i run this algoritm on Hadoop or in Eclips environment? Which is the best and easiest way? and How do I run? Please give me step by step what to do. Thank you

Comment: Have you written any code?

Comment: tanx, i am going to run an fp-growth algorithm that is available in its mahout.in other words, It is implemented by the mahout, and I want to run it by the eclips or hadoop environment. Now how do I implement this algorithm? Can you help me؟